# Efficiency and Instantiation - Java

Tags: java

I understand it might be hard to answer this question without knowing the details of the problem but I hope some one have encountered a similar situation before and could help me.

I am writing a simulator in Java and I have n neurons that communicate to each other during the simulation time. Each of these neurons have specific parameters and properties and I need to access and maybe manipulate their values during the simulation time.

I am wondering which of the following is the "right" choice:

1. Storing information in 1-D and 2-D arraylists - this means a lot of look ups and requires extra care to make sure information are linked properly.
2. Having one class with fields and methods required for a neuron and making different instances of it for every neuron (using the constructor to provide parameters specific to that neuron).

Basically, my question is where is the limit for making instances of a class? When does it become too many and inefficient? 100s? 1000s?

Let me know if I should explain more.

Appreciate any other suggestion as well.

Thank you.

Comment: "Efficiency" can only reasonably be measured on your computer with a profiler.  We can tell you that, between X and Y data structures it would have a specific or more efficient runtime, but efficiency is something you need to get knee-deep and profile for.

Comment: Use whichever will give you clearer code, and don't worry about efficiency until you have a problem with it.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." - Donald Knuth

Answer (score 0):

Only memory is a limit for making instances of a class, there are no other performance related issues with having many instances of classes(*).

However, class instances do have some additional information stored with them so they come with more memory overhead than using arrays.  For each instance of a class you can expect 16 bytes of overhead.

(*) In theory anyway, in practice you may encounter more GC overhead or have worse performance due to cache misses if the instances are not spread favorably in memory vs the array solution.